# Adding Fragment as a List Item

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having a situation in which as a List Item I want to inflate a Fragment, but It seems like a bad approach. As Fragments are processed/managed by Activity's FragmentManager or by child FragmentManager and list item views are  by ListView & ListAdapter.

Any comments and research regarding this would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your situation better.. This is too abstract to answer.

Comment: I have a fragment containing Audio/Video Player and also containing Some Notes/Dictation Input through Recording/Typing and also some other functionalities.

Now I want these functionalities as in a row of ListView, so I want to add a fragment as a ListView Item

Comment: and what is a problem with your Fragment?

Comment: No problem is with my Fragment, I would love to know either this approach is bad or good to go, will my app performance affected after doing this?

Comment: as i see the questions here Fragments are overused: i think 90% of SO folks use them as a "general navigation pattern" within one "god" Activity instead of using multiple specialized Activities, coming back to your case, if you properly use `convertView` paremeter in `getView` your performance shouldn't suffer

Comment: I don't know why down-vote ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use fragment as list item views because the API doesn't allow you - View and Fragment aren't even related so there's no way you can use it like that. Make custom views and use adapter getViewTypeCount and getView to use different list item behavior.

Fragment are managed by Activity's FragmentManager or by other Fragments child FragmentManager; while list item views are managed by ListView & ListAdapter. You can use ListViews in Fragments, but not the other way around.

I googled and got this.

Comment: you can use fragment inside list view. I dont know which version of API started allowing it. but i am sure I did that !!

Comment: I will give it a try then

Answer (score 1):

Here are my views and questions in mind on your problem.

You want to use ListView with fragments, since you already have a fragment which does that job and you dont want code to become redundant.

Though you can definitely use fragment, but i suppose its not the best practice. Fragments have their own life cycle and you are not going to use fragment life cycle methods (I suppose). Thus semantically it would not fit into this usecase.

And also your adapter will always be dependent on activity to retrieve fragments. (could there be any problems with orientation change again?)

List items and adapters are finetuned to work really well with scrolling really long lists. While the list view items get recycled when using view holder pattern, while scrolling, does any of fragment lifecycle methods come in between? would that cause performance impact. (I suppose yes. Havent tested it out yet)

You can instead have your view code in different layout file and include this layout in both fragment and also list adapter.

```
<include layout="@layout/YOUR_COMMON_VIEW_CODE"/>
```

and have utility class which takes the context and this layout container. Have all the functionality exposed inside that utility class.

Comment: I strongly agree with your answer and you understand my domain very accurately, still I am searching on it and till now I submitted an answer to my question.

Comment: Fortunately, my app is fixed to portrait, on other side there might be a chance for the android OS for calculating FPS in ListView after adding fragments as a row

Comment: yeah ok. more than anything. it does not sound semantically right. fragments are components which can "manage themselves" within a container, whereas listview items  "adapt" to the behavior insisted by adapter .